# Intel optane, does it have any benefit in Blender?

Tags: performance

I heard Intel optane has benefit in 3d application by making them load faster and other benefits include 3d modeling.
Blender already loads faster than the other 3d applications I use and we have the option of rendering using the GPU making the render more faster.
Does intel optane help in the performance of blender as well? If so what exactly are they?
Would really appreciate your answers.

Comment: Yeah, in general, they do improve performance. But not that much. And the improvement is actually a complicated system performance (mainly I/O response time, and throughput). So all application should benefit from optane, not only 3D application like Blender

Comment: Thanks for the info :D